# Drupal web page logging

Tags: views

I have a website built on drupal. I want to log (preferably db log) all the calls being made to a drupal page. The drupal page is called as shown here

`http://www.example.com/page-name?url=example2.com&redirect=example3.com&uid2=randomNumber`

I need to log all URL fields (url,redirect,uid2) alongwith timestamp and drupal user id.

Whats the best way to do it?

Comment: Only calls to `/page-name` or calls for all pages on the site, that include this parameters?

Comment: @user11153 only calls to `/page-name` including this parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module, for example:

`MODULENAME.install` file with [`hook_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) implementation:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_schema()
 */
function MODULENAME_schema() {
  $schema['MODULENAME'] = array(
    'description' => 'Description of the table.',
    'fields' => array(
      'timestamp' => array(
        'description' => 'Timestamp of the rquest.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      // definitions for the rest of fields here
    ),
    'indexes' => array(
      // define indexes
    ),
    'primary key' => array('NAME_OF_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELD'),
  );
  return $schema;
}

?>
```

`MODULENAME.module` file with [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) implementation:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  $items['page-name'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example title',
    'access callback' => TRUE, // imply no restrictions
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'MODULENAME_pagename_view',
  );
  return $items;
}

function MODULENAME_pagename_view() {
  global $user;
  // insert into Drupal database
  db_insert('MODULENAME')
    ->fields(array(
      'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'user_id' => $user->uid,
      'url' => $_GET['url'],
      'redirect' => $_GET['redirect'],
      'uid2' => $_GET['uid2'],
    ))
    ->execute();
}

?>
```

Comment: Pay attention to `access callback` and `title` in your `hook_menu` implementation.

Comment: @Ayesh K Good point, corrected.

Comment: @user11153 how can i log it in external/internal database??

Comment: @lavesh I updated my answer.